# java PDFPrint and PrintJobListener Always Returns printJobNoMoreEvents

Tags: java, pdf, printing

This is my code for printing a pdf file and getting it's events while performing the printing. my problem is that it allways goes to `printJobNoMoreEvents` and not into `printJobCompleted`. what could be the probelm? and how can i fix this? is it possible to check if the job was completed from within the `printJobNoMoreEvents` event ?

This is My code:

```
import com.qoppa.pdfPrint.PDFPrint;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobListener;

public class PdfPrint implements PrintJobListener{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try 
    {           
        // Create a printer job and get its PrintService
        PrinterJob pJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PrintService ps = pJob.getPrintService();

        // Load the PDF document and create SimpleDoc from it
        PDFPrint pdfPrint = new PDFPrint("C:\\temp\\file printing 1.pdf", null);
        SimpleDoc printDoc = new SimpleDoc(pdfPrint, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);

        // Get a doc print job from the service and set the listener and Printable 
        DocPrintJob docPrint = ps.createPrintJob();
        docPrint.addPrintJobListener(new PdfPrint());
        docPrint.print(printDoc, null);            

    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(PdfPrint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("printDataTransferCompleted");
}

@Override
public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("printJobCompleted");
}

@Override
public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("printJobFailed");
}

@Override
public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("printJobCanceled");
}

@Override
public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("printJobNoMoreEvents");
}

@Override
public void printJobRequiresAttention(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    System.out.println("printJobRequiresAttention");
}
```

}

Thakn's In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) set the Printer service Change this

```
PrintService ps = pJob.getPrintService();
PrinterJob pJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
```

to this

```
PrintService ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
```

when I tried .getPrintService() from PrintJob class, its only printDataTransferCompleted and printJobNoMoreEvents, it's not printing the pdf to Printer.

Descriptions on method events listener:

> printDataTransferCompleted() Data has been successfully transmitted
>   from the client to the print service.
>
> printJobNoMoreEvents() No more calls to any of the methods in this
>   interface will be called for this print job.
>
> printJobCompleted() The job has completed.

Then I tried PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService() to get default printer, it will print the pdf with printJobCompleted .

2) To load PDF Document, can use this

```
 String filename = "C:\\temp\\file printing 1.pdf";
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    Doc printDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);
```

Doesn't need to use qoppa

Answer (score -1):

The code is Standard JPS except the qoppa call which is their custom component. Have you asked qoppa about it?

Comment: no i didn't because it's not the problem. it happenes the same even when i don't use qoppa.. Any idea?